# Custom 'required' field message ignored for file uploads

Tags: 8, webforms

File upload fields in the D8 Webform module don't show my custom 'required' message when they fail validation.

Here's the YAML source of a simple Webform:

```
cv:
  '#type': managed_file
  '#title': CV
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Please upload a copy of your CV.'
  '#file_extensions': 'doc docx pdf odt rtf'
test_document:
  '#type': document_file
  '#title': 'Test document'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Custom missing document file message.'
  '#format_items': comma
```

Instead of *Please upload a copy of your CV* etc., I get the default:

> CV field is required.
>   Test document field is required.

I've run `drush webform:repair`
I've tested this on an otherwise empty form.
I've also cleared Drupal's cache.

Site setup:

Drupal 8.5.4.
No custom code yet.
(edit: we've since established it's nothing to do with contrib modules)

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, so it's a bug.

Comment: I suggest you report it over at the [issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform) page. The module's creator & maintainer [jrockowitz](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/972/jrockowitz) is pretty quick at fixing them.

Comment: Drupal core does not currently support the #required_error property for managed file uploads. @see \Drupal\file\Element\ManagedFile::validateManagedFile.  We might need to remove this feature.

Comment: Added my own answer, tidied question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message for managed_file fields is added by  [ManagedFile::validateManagedFile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Element%21ManagedFile.php/function/ManagedFile%3A%3AvalidateManagedFile/8.6.x) - it does not support `#required_error` - the 'file missing' message (and others) are hardcoded:

```
  $form_state
      ->setError($element, t('@name field is required.', [
      '@name' => $element['#title'],
    ]));
```

**This is presumably because of the multiple types of error possible:**

- file does not exist
- file is "not referenced" (it exists but is "unmanaged" - i.e. orphaned as far as DB concerned - see function docs linked above)
- or, in our case, a file has not been uploaded at all

**Workaround:**

I bypassed this by adding my own validation to the form.

The Webform module has `hook_webform_submission_form_alter` - you can use this to append your own validation method:

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ( $form['#webform_id'] != 'application' ) {
        // only do this for the specified form
        return;
    }

    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_fix_webform_validation';
}

function mymodule_fix_webform_validation($form, &$form_state) {

    // grab all the existing errors
    $errors = $form_state->getErrors();

    if ( isset( $errors['cv'] ) &&
         $errors['cv']->getUntranslatedString() == '@name field is required.' ) {
         // if (a) there's an error for this field, and
         // (b) it's the correct TYPE of error

         // reconstruct the error message
         // (you might add translatable strings if you need them)
         $errors['cv']->__construct( 'Please upload a copy of your CV.' );
    }

}
```

(Decided to use the constructor from reading [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246590/68872) to a similar question.)

**Things I tried first:**

The standard approach is to use $form_state->[setError()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetError/8.6.x) or [setErrorByName()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetErrorByName/8.6.x) - but neither appeared to have any effect on the error array - don't understand why.

On the actual form, the field was nested in a Webform "section"…

```
$form['elements']['uploads_section']['cv']
```

…so assumed I should supply the full array to setError(), for it to pull out the value of `#parents` and use that to construct the key.  Except the error is actually stored as a flat 'cv' key, without the parent.  Trying to set the 'cv' error using ByName didn't work either.

**Overriding strings:**

An alternative would be override the string (at time of writing, needs to be done programmatically: the [string overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module is not yet ready for D8). Add the following to `settings.php`:

```
$settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
    '@name field is required.' => 'Hello world!',
);
```

But this is a very broad brush and will apply to every file input on every form (plus anywhere else the phrase "*@name field is required.*" is used - you can't specify the `@name` placeholder).