# Change form validation error messages

Tags: theming, forms

In my theme I'm already using the hook_form_alter to customize the form fields but now I want to customize the validation error messages.

After some research, the only way I'm finding is to write a whole separate function and custom error handling of each form field.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Isn't there just a simple way to change the default form validation error so I can get away from "XYZ field is required?"

Comment: Hi and welcome to DA. Is the validation error message a *normal* status message or rather some javascript message showing up close to the field validated?

Comment: By customize you mean to change strings or the way it looks?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options to resolve this issue:

1. One option is using the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to replace the string used to generate the message.
2. Another option is to create a custom module that overrides the [validation function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#validate) for a particular form or field, replacing any error messages with the messages of your choosing.
3. The following link may also help:

   - [Custom Validation Message](https://drupal.org/node/742344)

Comment: Option 2 is what I'm currently working on. I was just thinking there would be an easier way to do it.