# How to define custom messages in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, status-messages

I want to show a custom message to user after he/she adds a new content of a specific type in Drupal 7. If I change the '@type %title has been created' to what I want the message will change for all content types.

How can I do it? Is there any module to define messages for different actions?

Comment: I briefly used the Custom Submit Message Module ( https://drupal.org/project/csm ) for a Drupal 6 project and saw that it has a Drupal 7 beta version that might be of interest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change form validation error messages in Drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75455/change-form-validation-error-messages-in-drupal-7)

Comment: @NikhilM, I do not think, its duplicate question.

Comment: you can do it with rules

Answer (score 3):

I just did this the other day, it's a bit of a hack, but I couldn't find another way.  The basic premise is to get and clear all current messages, loop through and call drupal_set_message() on all of them over again, changing the one you want:

```
<?php
/**
 * Submit function for the message node form.  Check for new message notification and change it.
 */
function mymodule_message_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];
  $t_args = array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node), '%title' => $node->title);
  $replace_message = t('@type %title has been created.', $t_args);

  // This call will get all messages and clear them from $_SESSION
  $messages = drupal_get_messages('status');
  foreach ($messages['status'] as $message) {

    if ($message == $replace_message) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Thank you your message has been sent successfully.  We will be in touch shortly.'));
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message($message);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this to replace an existing drupal message to my custom message.

```
function _exclude_message($mymessage, $mytype="status"){
$flag = false if ($messageArr = drupal_set_message()) {  foreach($messageArr as $type=>$messages) {
  if ($mytype==$type) {
    foreach($messages as $key=>$message) {
      if ($mymessage==$message) {
    unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type][intval($key)]);
       $flag = true;
      }
   }
  }
  if (count($_SESSION['messages'][$type])==0) unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type]);}} return $flag;}
```

`function my_theme_status_messages($display = NULL) {
  if (_exclude_message('Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="/user/password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>',"error")) drupal_set_message("Sorry, unrecognized username or password.","error");
 return theme_status_messages($display);
}`

under template.php

this code will replace existing "Sorry, unrecognized username or password. " with my custom message "Have you forgotten your password?".

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do that too. My solution is for error messages in validation hook. But should be quite the same for a confirmation message. You just have to find the id of the message (in my example the name of the field).

First I used a function to prevent the message from beeing sent.

```
function form_unset_error($name) {
   $errors = &drupal_static('form_set_error', array()); 
   $removed_messages = array();
   if (isset($errors[$name])) {
     $removed_messages[] = $errors[$name];
     unset($errors[$name]);
   }
   $_SESSION['messages']['error'] = array_diff($_SESSION['messages']['error'], $removed_messages);
   if (empty($_SESSION['messages']['error'])) {
     unset ($_SESSION['messages']['error']);
   }
}
```

So in my validation hook I unset the message and set a custom error message instead :

```
form_unset_error('field_name][und][0][value');
form_set_error('field_name', t('Custom error message translated'), $limit_validation_errors = NULL);
```

Hope it helps.