# How to override checkout form validation error message?

Tags: 7, ubercart, forms

Im using D7 and Ubercart 3. But I think this is more a form question than anything else. When validating the checkout form I get a list of errors saying fields are required. And thats all fun and stuff, but I just want the error to say:

> Please complete the form by filling out the highlighted fields.

And only once off course.

Comment: I think this will be of use to you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12280/how-do-i-change-a-core-error-message

Comment: @jdu it does not i came across this post before. But this guys wants to change te message. I want to remove existing messages and replace all of them with one global message.

Comment: I'll post as an answer to outline the process, but the functions to do it are explained in the above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use:  [`theme_status_messages`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7).

First, use [`drupal_get_messages`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7) to clear the queue.

Then, use [`drupal_set_message`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) to add your new generic message.

Answer (score 0):

Although @jdu solution will get you there, it seems like it will effect all messages rather than target this specific form.  I would be inclined to use something a bit more specific:

Within template.php OR a custom module:

```
function themename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'formid_form') {
    array_push($form['#validate'], 'custom_form_validation');
  }
}

function custom_form_validation($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($_SESSION['messages']['error']) {
    drupal_get_messages('error');
    drupal_set_message('Please review the form for errors', 'error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I'd still want to find a solution that lets me know whether the form failed validation, and act upon that (rather than rely on `$_SESSION`).  That being said, I'm not sure it exists out of the box with Drupal.  You'd have to replace the default form validation from `$form['#validate']` (as opposed to pushing onto it) and run your own validation with [drupal_validate_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_validate_form/7)

Answer (score 0):

By default the common validation messages is provided by [IFE](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife) module.

Other alternative could be to use [Field validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) and its form validation rules (*Required field* rule). Alternatively check [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module with the relevant condition/action rules.